# Can't delete using IN

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this syntax:

```
DELETE FROM customer WHERE id IN ('1,3')
```

Customer table:

[image]

It deletes only the row with id = 1. I'm expecting empty table. If I leave there only one row with id=3, it says that deleted records: 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for `'` around values:

```
DELETE FROM customer WHERE id IN (1,3);
```

Comment: well, I've seen lots of examples, but I couldn't notice these single quotes `'` around my code till now when you have pointed here. Thanks a lot. Now, it works as expecting.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a single value that is a string with three characters:  `'1,3'`, not two numeric values.

If you are constructing the query, then you should try to construct it with a proper `in` list.  Under some circumstances, you might find it more convenient to use `find_in_set()`:

```
DELETE FROM customer WHERE find_in_set(id, '1,3') > 0
```

However, this cannot use an index, so lad2025 is a better general solution.

Comment: How come it deleted row `id = 1` if there should be string with `'1,3'`? Referring to your answer I would expect to delete the first row when I'd have given just  `'1'`

Comment: @soonic . . . Because it converted the string to an integer, using silent conversion.  The leading integers are used, so `1,3` --> 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use single quotes around **Number** fields. You are supposed to use single quotes around **character** values.